# To Insert data from multiple databse to one

Tags: database, vba

I am beginner to the VBA. Please help.
 I have a database named as "Master" saved on shared network folder and it has table named as "logs" . 
I have few users who have different data base with the table “logs” and this table structure is like the same as in the table “log” in the database “Master”.
Those users makes entries to their database table “logs” everyday. I want that in the “Master” database, I will create a table named as “UserDb” which will keep address path of all the users database files and I will create a form with the button “Sync”.
I need that once I click on the “Sync” button then it should read path of the user data base from the table “UserDb” and insert all the today’s date entries from all the user’s data base table “logs” to the “Master” database table “logs”.
In the table “Logs” columns names are UserName, Application, TeamName, StartTime, StopTime, LoginDate.

Comment: I would highly suggest you read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: What kind of database? MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that you can start with:

```
Function ConToDataBase(DBPath As String) As Variant
Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Logs"
Set Con = New ADODB.Connection
With Con
.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & DBPath & ";"
.Open
End With
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.Open SQL, Con
Dim Var As Variant
Var = Rs.GetRows
ConToDataBase = Var
Set Rs = Nothing
Con.Close
End Function
```

Make sure to add the reference Microsoft ActiveX Objects 2.8 from Tools > References so that you can ADODB objects.

The function will return a variant containing the logs table. You can take it from there.